# Footer will not center

Tags: html, css, footer

I'mkind of knew so I have no idea if I'm formatting this correctly, but my question is: How do center the footer to the middle of the page (vertically of course)?

```
<!-- Header & footer-->
 <header>
 <style type="text/css">
  body {
  font-family : Verdana, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif, arial ;
background-color: #C2A366;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-left:400px;
}
p.padding
{
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-right:50px;
padding-left:0px;
}
</style> 
</header>

<footer><table align="center">
<tr><td align="left"><p class="padding"><font color="white">Phone: 555-555-1800<br>Fax:         555-555-1800<br>Canada:1-800-555-5555<br>Mexico:001-800-555-5555</p></font></td>
<td align="left"> <p> <font color="white"> company title<br>Street<br>City, State         zip<br>
  <a href="mailto:emailadress@host" style="text-decoration:none"> <font color="white">     email adress</a></p></font></td></tr>
  </table><table align="center">
  <tr><td><p class="padding"><font color="white" font size="2"> copy write 2014     yatayata </tr></td>
 </table> </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: why you giving `margin-left:400px;` on body tag?

Comment: It originally had a purpose, but since nothing happened when I deleted it, It wasn't serving a purpose anymore

Comment: Luke can you check my answer below.. might be solves your problem

Comment: just a moment kind sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several method to `vertically center`.. here is one of them. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zofenoca/1/edit)** first.

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
html {display:table;}

body {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
   font-family : Verdana, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif, arial ;
background-color: #C2A366;
}
p.padding
{
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-right:50px;
padding-left:0px;
}
```

Comment: It's most likely because of the other coding I ommited from this question but that didn't work. I'm using margin-left:400px to help re-adjust certain jpgs. I will  keep trying though

Comment: The answer is provided here on the basis of the question you asked. `how to center the footer.`

Answer (score 0):

**Now its centered , Tested**

```
<header>
 <style type="text/css">
  body {
  font-family : Verdana, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif, arial ;
background-color: #C2A366;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
p.padding
{
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-right:50px;
padding-left:0px;
}
</style> 
</header>

<footer><table align="center">
<tr><td align="left"><p class="padding"><font color="white">Phone: 555-555-1800<br>Fax:         555-555-1800<br>Canada:1-800-555-5555<br>Mexico:001-800-555-5555</p></font></td>
<td align="left"> <p> <font color="white"> company title<br>Street<br>City, State         zip<br>
  <a href="mailto:emailadress@host" style="text-decoration:none"> <font color="white">     email adress</a></p></font></td></tr>
  </table><table align="center">
  <tr><td><p class="padding"><font color="white" font size="2"> copy write 2014     yatayata </tr></td>
 </table> </footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove
"

```
margin-right:0px;
margin-left:400px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
```

"
from body

You should use margin auto for center.

add in body

"`margin: 0 auto;` "

Answer (score 0):

Use `<center>` tag

Link: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khursheed_Ali/a8HPY/)

```
<html>
<style>
  body {
  font-family : Verdana, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif, arial ;
background-color: #C2A366;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-left:0px;
}
p.padding
{
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-right:50px;
padding-left:0px;
}
</style>

<body>
<footer>
  <center>  
<table align='center'>
<tr><td align="left"><p class="padding"><font color="white">Phone: 555-555-1800<br>Fax:         555-555-1800<br>Canada:1-800-555-5555<br>Mexico:001-800-555-5555</p></font></td>
<td align="left"> <p> <font color="white"> company title<br>Street<br>City, State         zip<br>
  <a href="mailto:emailadress@host" style="text-decoration:none"> <font color="white">     email adress</a></p></font></td></tr>
  </table><table align="center">
  <tr><td><p class="padding"><font color="white" font size="2"> copy write 2014     yatayata </tr></td>
 </table>  
    </center>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `<center>` element was deprecated since HTML 4. see here. http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/center